# How to set Node version used in dotnet build in Azure DevOps hosted pipelines?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I am using an Azure DevOps Microsoft-hosted build agent (windows-latest) and can't figure out how to set the Node version that is being used during the dotnet build step. I am trying to manually specify to use 18.17.0 and the agent seems to insist on using 16.20.0. I set the Node version, not sure why it seems to completely disregard that and go with it's own version.

This is my build pipeline:

```
parameters:
  - name: relativeWebProjectPath
    type: string
  - name: buildConfiguration
    type: string
  - name: artifactFeed
    type: string

steps:
  - task: UseNode@1
    inputs:
      version: '18.17.0'
  - script: 'node --version'
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: "Use .NET 7.x"
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '7.x'
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet restore'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      vstsFeed: '${{ parameters.artifactFeed }}'
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet build'
    env:
      NODE_OPTIONS: '--openssl-legacy-provider'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '${{ parameters.relativeWebProjectPath }}'
      arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }} --no-restore --verbosity diagnostic'
```

In the build, the dotnet build step fails with:

```
C:\agents\3.224.1\externals\node16\bin\node.exe: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
##[error]Exit code 9 returned from process: file name 'C:\agents\3.224.1\externals\node16\bin\node.exe', arguments '"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.221.0\dotnetcore.js"'.
```

I'm not sure where it got Node 16.20.0 from or how to override it. The UseNode step succeeds, and `node --version` prints out 18.17.0 as expected. It doesn't seem to use node from the PATH, and uses it's own install directory instead.

```
C:\agents\3.224.1\externals\node16\bin\node.exe --version
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\03a2e5c6-f53d-49d7-9ee8-4fcfd958d484.cmd""
v16.20.0

node --version
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\8068aabe-dbfb-499d-8c9e-c07740887d86.cmd""
v18.17.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by overwriting the node versions added by DevOps with the correct version from the PATH, via PowerShell

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'FixNodeWithPowerShell'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/devops/templates/Fix-Node.ps1'
```

And then in a separate powershell script I keep next to my yaml build defs --

```
$NodeExePath = (get-command node).Path

cd C:\agents
cd (Get-ChildItem -Directory)[0]
cd externals
foreach ($NodeDir in (Get-ChildItem .\node* -Directory)) {
    Copy-Item -Path $NodeExePath -Destination "$($NodeDir)\bin\node.exe" -Force
}
```